# How to authorize my app through facebook and fetch facebook user information using Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am able to login to facebook from my app by integrating Facebook latest SDK i.e. 3.0 
But now I want to fetch user information and I am not able to find a way to do so. All links I am getting from google and stack is for the old version of facebook sdk. Also I would like to know how to authorize an app through facebook.
In older versions we were doing it by:

Facebook facebook = new Facebook(appId);

But these things are deprecated in sdk 3.0.

Please can anyone help me out on these issues or provide links having good tutorials or sample examples!

Thanks

Comment: Check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

U need the add the appId in manifest

Comment: Thanks for your help but I did that in the manifest and thats why I was able to login. And in the tutorial you suggested, they are doing it through fragments so not of much help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an open session you execute a new **me** request.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {    
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (user != null) {
                if (response.getError() == null){
                    //Do what you want with the user object
                }
                else {
                    //Do something with the error
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As said on [facebook developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/fetch-user-data/) : "the user data you can access depends on the permissions a user has granted your app along with the data a user has chosen to share with apps."
So you have to add the needed permission in respect to what specific fields you want.

For the app authorization you should follow the [Create a Facebook App section](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) for the Facebook SDK for android.
But if you already have a working login you shouldn't need further operations.

Comment: I already have a working login but when i run the above given code it is not returning anything. Can you please also guide on how to add the needed permission? Is it not returning anything because it might not have permission?

Comment: @nidhi You need to me more clear. What do you mean with "it is not returning anything"? You mean you get a null user or even a null session?
If you follow the instructions for the SDK 3.0, using the LoginButton with .setReadPermissions(READ_PERMISSIONS) you can set before the login all the read permissions that you need.

Comment: I made simple demo and it worked perfectly. I think I have messed up the things in my project. Thanks for your help!